# Improve answer acceptance by notifying users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

I see a lot of questions which:

- Have an answer which has a comment from the question asker with something like "thanks it works". Or
- Have a very good answer, but the user no longer takes care of the question.

On both cases the answer isn't marked as accepted. However the user is still asking new questions (so he is still using the community).

I think that this might happen due to the reason that the user no longer remembers that question and/or didn't care about accepting an answer. So I'm currently thinking about some ways which might be possible to improve the situation. So what about:

- Give the user some reputation when they accept an answer for their questions. It might be useful for other users to see that the answer is working so giving some reputation points might be useful.
- Another idea is to adjust the top bar and add an option which shows open questions asked by the user. Via that, they would constantly see a counter and be informed that there is still something open which still needs his attention. To avoid the counter growing as the user has more questions with no answer it might be useful to show only open questions from the past 6 months. Or this value could only show pending questions where the user didn't comment on answers. So if an answer isn't working for the user he could add a comment like "it's not working for me".
- Another option might be to send out an email notification to inform the user that there are still answers which must be accepted.

This might help us to improve the quality of questions and answers. As we then get more "valid" and controlled answers. Many users spend a lot of time and knowledge answering questions so I think improving the situation might be a win win for the community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This might help us to improve the quality of questions and answers. As we then get more "valid" and controlled answers.

No, that's not the case. 'Controlled' means that it is tested/verified by *other* members of the community, and that is measured by up- and downvotes. Those are way more important than an answer being accepted or not.

> Give the user some reputation when they accept an answer for their questions. It might be useful for other users to see that the answer is working so giving some reputation points might be useful.

This already happens: you gain [2 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/295232) for accepting an answer (other than your own answer).

> Have an answer which has a comment from the question asker with something like "thanks it works".

In this case, especially in the case of a new user, other users will remind him/her (with a comment) that he/she should accept the answer. When used sparingly, this isn't a problem at all.